# Load raster from Requester-Pays S3 bucket into QGIS

Tags: qgis, landsat, amazon-s3

I have successfully requested Landsat data from the USGS S3 bucket by following the [provided tutorial](https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/landsat-cloud-direct-access-requester-pays-tutorial). Now I want to pull a raster directly into QGIS via the Data Source Manager.

I have set my `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables under Preferences > System > Environment, and configured my request as shown in the image below.

[image: screenshot of QGIS Data Source Manager config modal]

When I click the Add button, I get the error:

```
Unsupported Data Source: /vsis3/usgs-landsat/collection02/level-1/standard/oli-tirs/2022/027/030/LC08_L1TP_027030_20220213_20220222_02_T1/LC08_L1TP_027030_20220213_20220222_02_T1_B8.TIF is not a supported raster data source.
```

I believe my issue is that the request QGIS sends is missing the required `x-amz-request-payer` header, but I'm not sure how to add it in the UI. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by setting the Gdal environment variable `AWS_REQUEST_PAYER=requester` in the same place as the others above.